# I have an RFID reader with a Serial and USB output, and I want to write a program that reads the tags and sends POST http-requests

Tags: serial-port, polling, hid

I'm a beginner so I haven't really tried anything yet, except for these:
https://web.dev/serial/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

RFID reader: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07YZ8NW22/ref=ox_sc_act_title_2?smid=A24KK1JV764V60&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07YZ8NW22)

But they haven't worked for me. Can someone give me some pointers on or even better help me writing a program that receives data from the serial Port and somehow sends data to a database?

Resources I currently have: Rpi and beginner knowledge in JavaScript and C#

Edit: I want the RFID-reader to read tags, and maybe use a Rpi to send POST-HTTP Requests containg the tag information to a database. I have received a SDK from the manufacturer in different languages(C#,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start by asking the manufacturer if they have a developer manual or maybe an SDK to use in your application. Depending on what exactly is your requirement, it will help you to determine which programming language to use, but I would say C#.NET is a good choice, whether you want to program a windows application or a middleware (Windows service).

I hope this may help you.

Comment: Hey @MarioV, I did get in contact with them and indeed they've sent a SDK, for various languages(including C#). But I'm still lost in how to use it, could you maybe give a more in depth explanation?

Comment: Can you provide more information on what is your problem right now? will you use C# for your development? have you managed to create a new solution in C# and include in your solution the SDK library provided by the vendor?